# Java 9 with Gatling

Tags: java, gatling, java-9

Anybody knows if nowadays `Gatling` has support for Java 9?.

We're considering to migrate to Java 9 but our performance and Volume test are really important. We are using the version `2.2.2`.

I tried [finding something](https://gatling.io/?s=java+9) on their site, in the blog area and no news about supporting Java 9. Has anyone tried the combination already?

Comment: Did you check on their official site? Any other research? What did it say?

Comment: No official info in site https://gatling.io/ or at least I could not find it, that´s why I´m asking here.  https://gatling.io/?s=java+9 Nothing in their blogs

Comment: Lets wait for the officials to pitch in that case, though a suggestion would be that this could have been asked on their mailing list as well.

Comment: I did that already, but I'm afraid Gatling people are not willing to response very often. Again that's the reason why I ask in this channel. To see if the community already try it

Comment: Well, when a web search doesn't reveal anything ... then asking a question here isn't always a solution...

Comment: I don't know anything about Gatling but it looks like they have a bug where they assume that the TCCL is of type URLClassLoader (see https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3359). I'm surprised they haven't run into that in other environments as the TCCL is often set to other types of class loader.

Answer (score 1):

See this for more information :

- https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3364

Support for Java 9 has been added as part of the commercial solution FrontLine but is not yet available to public:

- https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3359

I don't know when it will be , probably in 3.0.0 scheduled for March 2018 if schedule is respected.